# query method to copy .pdf, .html, .jpeg files

Tags: python, p2p

```
def fetch(self, query, secret):
    if secret != self.secret: raise AccessDenied
    result = self.query(query)
    f = open(join(self.dirname, query), 'w')
    f.write(result)
    f.close()
    return 0
```

I am trying to get peers fetch files from one host to another using this method(peer-to-peer program). 
This method only takes text as it is opening the file and writing the contents to f.

How can I copy .pdf , .mpeg, jpeg files copied/downloaded to the peers directory!

Answer (score 2):

To write binary data you should open the file using the [file mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) `'wb'` (write binary).  i.e.:

```
f = open(join(self.dirname, query), 'wb')
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as your query method supports binary, try `'wb'` instead of `'w'`.